# Diary App for Mac OS X (equivalent to Chronories)

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, software-recommendation, mac, leopard

I am looking for Diary App for my MacBook (Leopard) and MacBookPro (Snow Leopard)

One of the famous Diary App is Chronories ([link](http://www.syniumsoftware.com/chronories/)), but I need something else (if it's free, it would be good)

**EDIT:** I basically need a diary, that's my only requirement. But I need some free alternatives too. BTW, I have never used Chronories, I just knew about that app, so I mentioned it here.

Comment: What are the main features you would like to keep for the new tool and, most important, why do you need something else?

Comment: Please check edits in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my query, it GrowlyBird's [Journal](http://growlybird.com/GrowlyBird/Journal.html) App.

Have a look at it, and tell me.

Comment: I find the interface too flashy (ugly to be honest! :) But if it fulfills your needs and you have everything you need, then it's the right one!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly what features of Chronories you use the most and would like to find in another tool but here are two possibilities.

- [MacJournal](http://www.marinersoftware.com/products/macjournal/)
- [Mémoires](http://www.codingrobots.com/memoires/)

Both work on Leopard and its snowy friend.

---

*edit following question's clarification:*

With low requirements and going for free solutions, you could simply go to [EverNote](http://www.evernote.com/). You'll have as a bonus the possibility to sync your notes from everywhere, including mobile devices.
You have the possibility to order your notes by date, which would then mimics a diary. It's far less sexy than the above solutions but could fulfill your requirements.

---

*second edit*
A new one I saw today on the Mac App Store:

- [Day One](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/day-one/id422304217?mt=12)

Seems quite nice, low price and good feedback until now.

Comment: Thank You, and can you please check the EDITs in my question, and reply back.

Comment: Out of MacJournal and Memoires, what is your personal recommandation for my needs. Any one please.

Comment: @I-M-JM Added a new suggestion after I saw it on the Mac App Store

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to forgo Mac-only software and consider the web as a viable option, [OhLife](http://ohlife.com/) is a fantastic diary/journaling website.  They email you either daily (same time each day) or weekly, and all you have to to is respond to the email with your entry.  They do offer a download feature so you can collect all of your old entries if you'd like to keep them offline.  Rather than waste your time, I'll let their website explain the rest.

The best part of all? It's completely free.

**Update**: As of October 19, 2014, OhLife shut down[2](http://ohlife.com/shutdown) (as pointed out by [Vishwas](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/diary-app-for-mac-os-x-equivalent-to-chronories/12399?noredirect=1#comment195046_12399))

Comment: Sweet idea, nice service. I upvote this one!

Comment: It shut down in 2014

Answer (score 1):

For me, I think **Day One** is the best personal journaling app. It's simple, beautiful, and syncs across multiple platforms via **Dropbox** and [iCloud](http://www.geekswithjuniors.com/blog/2013/5/14/10-reasons-to-love-icloud.html). I think Apple even selected it as the **Best App of the Year** in the **Mac App Store** last year.

Here's a complete [Day One app review](http://www.geekswithjuniors.com/blog/2012/10/10/day-one.html) that my best friend, Ray, has written thoroughly. It covers how he uses the app both on his Mac and on his iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I like [750words](http://750words.com) a lot, lately. It's a free online service with some of the features it appears Chronories has, as well as the ability to parse your entries and gather "emotional metadata" about your writing. It's more writer-focused, with a goal of getting you to write at least 750 words every day.

[Journler](http://journler.com/) is/was a great journaling app. The developer ceased development last year and open-sourced the code. He recently announced a new journal app built from the ground up called [Per Se](http://www.getsprouted.com/applications/perse/), which looks great and is free up to 20 entries, $19.95 after that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "[Clover Diary](http://homepage.mac.com/nsekine/SYW/software/english/cloverdiary/index.html)". A very simple and easy to use Diary.